# Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, xcode9

I am new to swift and coding in general and am working on making a simple web browser app from a tutorial off youtube and I'm running into some errors.  Any changes I could make?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func settings(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var mysettings: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebviewer: UIWebView!
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    mywebviewer.loadrequest(URLRequest(url: URL(String:"https://www.google.com")!))
    }


 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7fDK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try move closing bracket `}` from line 16 to line 31.

Currently your `ViewController` class has scope from line 11 to 16, while it should contains all methods visible on your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Frist Remove Curley bracket which locate after IBOutlet and add in last line of your view controller class because this is a main class bracket